# Subset a data by date to create the summary in R

Tags: r

I have a datset where I have data from 1997 to 2009 and I want to subset the data according to date.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
creek <- read.csv("wolfcreek.csv")
library(ggplot2)
creek[1:10,]
colnames(creek) <- c("date","flow")
creek$date <- as.Date(creek$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The code I used to create the subset is as follows:

```
creek1 <- subset(creek, as.Date(date) > (01-01-2000) & as.Date(date) <(01-01-2009))
```

But when I try to see the summary of creek1 I get

```
> creek1
[1] date flow
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can anyone tell what I did wrong here ?

The dataset I used can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqpena3nk82x67e/creek.csv

Thank you so much.

Best Regards, 
Jdbaba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert the column date, it is already in on the class Date.
Then you need to cretae dateMin, and dateMax coercing a string to a date.

Here I give the string in the right format, otherwise you need to use `format` (like in  @Mathew answer)

```
subset(creek, date > as.Date("2000-01-01") & date < as.Date("2009-01-01"))
```

Here, I would use package `xts` for his fast subsetting and concise syntax

```
library(xts)
dat.xts <- as.xts(creek$flow, order.by=creek$date)
dat.xts['2000-01/2009-01'] ## powerful and fast!!
```

using `quantmod` for example, It is time series so wee need to use the suitable package to treat it.
Here I subset, and I plot (I zoom my time series)

```
 chart_Series(dat.xts['2000-01/2000-09'])
```

[image]

Comment: @ agstudy: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and showing different options. I had used xts in past but haven't really dived into it.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the dates to the numbers -2000 and -2009 (1-1-2000 and 1-1-2009) rather than dates.

```
creek1 <- subset(creek, date > as.Date('01-01-2000', '%m-%d-%Y') & date < as.Date('01-01-2009', '%m-%d-%Y'))
```